# When i check the checkbox for the first time the program executes.But after unchecking,NOT

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Here is my script.

When I check the checkbox for the first time the program executes. But after unchecking (it will hide the output), when I want to check it again it will not show my results.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#chk input').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // checkbox is checked -> do something
        var url=$(this).attr('value');
             $('#headlines').load('Subcri.php?searchquery='+ url);
             return false;
    } else {
        // checkbox is not checked -> do something different
       $('#headlines').hide();
    }

});

}); // end ready
```

Here is my `html` part

```
<html>

<form id="chk" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<input type="checkbox" name="searchquery" class="click" id="" value="bird" >Checkbox 
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="searchquery" class="click" id="" value="pet" >Checkbox
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="searchquery" class="click" id="" value="school" >Checkbox
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="searchquery" class="click" id="" value="Disney" >Checkbox

<br />

</form>

<div id="headlines"></div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not show headline div after hiding it. you need to show it  if it is hidden.

replace your js script by this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#chk input').change(function(){

        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // checkbox is checked -> do something
            var url=$(this).attr('value');
                 if(! $('#headlines').is(":visible")){
                    $('#headlines').show();
                  }
                 $('#headlines').load('Subcri.php?searchquery='+ url);
                 return false;
        } else {
            // checkbox is not checked -> do something different
           $('#headlines').hide();
        }

    });

    }); // end ready
```

live demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qsDn5/15/

Answer (score 1):

Use This

```
if(! $('#headlines').is(":visible")){
   $('#headlines').show();
}
```

It wil Show